# ¿Como hacer que se genere un codigo automatico con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

necesito que en una caja de texto aparezca un codigo generado por javascript que podra ver el usuario, este codigo podria ser de formato: nota001 y se incremente como: nota002... nota003 y asi o algo similar, gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Que haz intentado? Puedes dejad el codigo que hasta ahora tienes?

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te propongo un *generador de códigos común* ya que no esta aclarado cual seria el uso del este `código`.

> - La función `generarCodigo`, genera un código de longitud `largo`, valor que es customizable.
> - El código generado es totalmente al azar y utiliza `mapa` para definir los caracteres posibles para este nuevo código.

```js
function generarCodigo(largo) {
    var mapa = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
      codigo = '',
      i = 0;
  
    for(i; i < largo; i++) {
        codigo += mapa.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * mapa.length));
    }
    return codigo;
}

function imprimirCodigo() {
  var largo = parseInt(document.getElementById('largo').value, 10) || 5;
  document.getElementById('codigo').innerHTML = generarCodigo(largo);
}
```

```html
Codigo: <span id="codigo"></span>
<br/>
<input id="largo" type="number" value="5" min="5" />
<button type="button" onclick="imprimirCodigo()">Generar</button>
```